# get text from selected radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, radgridview

i get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. and here the code

```
  <asp:radiobuttonlist id="JAN" runat="server">
              <asp:listitem id="radL" runat="server" value="L" />
              <asp:listitem id="radP" runat="server" value="P" />
              </asp:radiobuttonlist>
```

code behind:

```
 protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
                    {
                      try
                    {
                      GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
                      RadioButtonList JAN = (RadioButtonList)editedItem.FindControl("JAN");
                       string GENDER = JAN.SelectedValue;

                       foreach (ListItem item in JAN.Items)
                       { 
                         if (item.Selected)
                       {
                          GENDER = item.Value;
                        } 
                      } 
                      SqlConnection conn1 = BusinessTier.getConnection();
                      conn1.Open();
                      int flg = BusinessTier.SavePersonalInfo(conn1, 1,JAN.SelectedItem.Value,)
                      BusinessTier.DisposeConnection(conn1);
```

Comment: at which line do you get that error ?

Comment: RadioButtonList JAN = (RadioButtonList)editedItem.FindControl("JAN"); The main issue is at above line. "editedItem" doesnt find the control named "JAN". your JAN is null. so thats why you are getting "object reference not set to an instance" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be because of, 
1) you have not checked if the RadioButtonList is null or not. And the error is because of you are not getting reference of RadioButtonList.
check below code:

```
protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
                {
                  try
                {
                  GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
                  RadioButtonList JAN = (RadioButtonList)editedItem.FindControl("JAN");

                 **// add below code**
                  if(JAN==null)
                  {
                     // print some error message..
                     return;
                   }

                   string GENDER = JAN.SelectedValue;

                   foreach (ListItem item in JAN.Items)
                   { 
                     if (item.Selected)
                   {
                      GENDER = item.Value;
                    } 
                  } 
                  SqlConnection conn1 = BusinessTier.getConnection();
                  conn1.Open();
                  int flg = BusinessTier.SavePersonalInfo(conn1, 1,JAN.SelectedItem.Value,)
                  BusinessTier.DisposeConnection(conn1);
```

2) and you have passed selected item value to some function directly.

```
int flg = BusinessTier.SavePersonalInfo(conn1, 1,JAN.SelectedItem.Value,)
```

But there can be case that multiple items are selected.